# PowerBI Online vs Desktop Credentials for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I created a report, which uses DirectQuery on Power BI desktop. On the desktop app, I am able to connect to my SQL Server and retrieve the queries. However, after publishing the report online I get an error The data source '' is missing credentials and cannot be accessed. I have all the credentials in the desktop and cleared and reentered the credentials, but I am still getting the same error online.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the dataset page in the Power BI Service web app, and you should see credential errors, with a link to fix it.

If it's Azure SQL DB, that's all that should be needed.

If the server is on-premises, you'll also need to configure the gateway and make sure it works.

Comment: the dataset settings page never loads though