# Missing credientials error when trying to access a published Power BI report that runs a SQL query on Azure SQL Server

Tags: powerbi, azure-sql

I can run my Power BI report fine on the desktop. It connects to an Azure SQL table. I connect as 'Direct query' with a username and password.

Once I publish the report, I got the following error message:

> The datasource xxxxx is missing credentials and cannot be accessed.

There is a 'show details' link that opens a dialog which itself has a link to 'xxxx dataset settings page'. However that page never ends loading and remains empty.

My post is surely redundant with this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58616839/powerbi-online-vs-desktop-credentials-for-sql-server) but the only answer there doesn't help and the post lost traction.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it working.

Within Power Bi online, on the left menu I navigated to 'Dataset' then I selected my dataset then on the top menu there was 'File' then 'Settings'. In the settings pane there was my connection error and I could re-enter my credentials.